# Variant of \left, \right, ...that gets ignored in inlinemath

Tags: delimiters

I am trying to construct a variant of \left, \right, and \middle that are ignored in inlinemath.

Intended behavior:

`\[ \lft( 2^{2^2} \rgt) \]` -> behaves as `\[ \left( 2^{2^2} \right) \]`

`\( \lft( 2^{2^2} \rgt) \)` -> behaves as `\( ( 2^{2^2} ) \)`

Help would be much appreciated.

Disclaimer:

- Attempts to get this behavior using `mathchoice` was not successful.
  The problem seems to be that stuff like `\mathchoice{\left}{}{}{}` is invalid because TeX expects the delimiter (and the corresponding `\right`) within the same group.
- Attempts to get the desired behavior by influencing the order of expansion (e.g. with `noexpand`) were unsuccessful, but I'm not a pro regarding this stuff.
- I know that some people think that one should not automate the usage of `\left` and `\right`. I would like to have this anyhow (-:
- I know that I could simply defining something like `\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\mathchoice{\left(#1\right)}{(#1)}{(#1)}{(#1)}}`. However, my problem still occurs if the argument contains `\middle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how useful this can be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lft}{\if@display\expandafter\left\fi}
\newcommand{\mdl}{\if@display\expandafter\middle\fi}
\newcommand{\rgt}{\if@display\expandafter\right\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}% just to make a smaller picture
\( \lft( 2^{2^2} \rgt) \)
\end{center}
\[
\lft( 2^{2^2} \rgt)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: `amsmath` does `\everydisplay{\@displaytrue}`.

Comment: Why are the `\expandafter`s needed here?

Comment: @user125730 They are not strictly needed, because `\left`, `\middle` and `\right` will expand the `\fi` anyway, but getting rid of the `\fi` before delivering the “true” or “false” texts is generally better.